# how to avoid localStorage from rendering from the beginning

Tags: javascript

#### CODE

Here's the code for a function which is triggered when a person clicks on "Add to Cart" button. It creates a row inside the cart using the data from localStorage about the items selected by the user from the menu.

```
function addItemToCart() {
  
  var cartRow = document.createElement("div");
  cartRow.classList.add("cart-row");
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-items")[0]; //<div class="cart-items">
  var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName("cart-item-title");
  //Putting the data
  var locStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedProduct"));
  var cartRowContents = locStore.map((item) => {
    return `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${item.image}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${item.title}</span>
            <span class="cart-item-size">"Rs.${item.sizePrice}"</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${item.price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`;
  });
  cartRowContents = cartRowContents.join("");

  cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
  cartItems.append(cartRow);
  cartRow
    .getElementsByClassName("btn-danger")[0]
    .addEventListener("click", removeCartItem);
  cartRow
    .getElementsByClassName("cart-quantity-input")[0]
    .addEventListener("change", quantityChanged);
}
```

#### ISSUE

Whenever the user clicks on "Add TO cart", the item is stored in localStorage. 
Now, let's say I have one item in my localStorage something like this:-

```
[{"productID":"1","image":"http://127.0.0.1:5500/Images/pizza.png","price":300,"title":"Tandoori Pizza","sizePrice":"100","quantity":1}]
```

Using the above data, I create a row in my Cart. Till here, it works completely fine.
Now, I add another item in my localStorage and now the localStorage looks something like this:-

```
[{"productID":"1","image":"http://127.0.0.1:5500/Images/pizza.png","price":300,"title":"Tandoori Pizza","sizePrice":"100","quantity":1},
{"productID":"2","image":"http://127.0.0.1:5500/Images/pizza.png","price":350,"title":"Veggie Supreme","sizePrice":"100","quantity":1}]"
```

Now, `addItemToCart()` is triggered again as we have selected another item. This time, it will show two items in a single row because it is also considering the first item in localStorage which actually has already been considered.
What should I do to avoid this problem?

#### OUTPUT - UI (CART)

[image: Cart looks like this on UI. You can see that Tandoori Paneer is coming twice in the cart.]

Comment: Just check if an item with the product id already exists and skip that.

Comment: Yes, "Tandoori Pizza" is the first object in localStorage and thus it gets added in the cart right away once I click on Add To Cart button, then I add "Veggie Supreme" in my cart. The moment I click on Add to Button now, it considers the already present "Tandoori Pizza" in localStorage and shows it along with "Veggie Supreme" in the cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do (note that I can't test it without the whole context):

```
function addItemToCart(item) {
  
  var cartRow = document.createElement("div");
  cartRow.classList.add("cart-row");
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-items")[0]; //<div class="cart-items">
  var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName("cart-item-title");
  //Putting the data
  var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${item.image}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${item.title}</span>
            <span class="cart-item-size">"Rs.${item.sizePrice}"</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${item.price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`;
  cartRowContents = cartRowContents.join("");

  cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
  cartItems.append(cartRow);
  cartRow
    .getElementsByClassName("btn-danger")[0]
    .addEventListener("click", removeCartItem);
  cartRow
    .getElementsByClassName("cart-quantity-input")[0]
    .addEventListener("change", quantityChanged);
}

/**
 * Render all the items in cart, 
 * call this instead of addItemToCart after an item was added to local storage.
 **/
function renderItemsInCart() {
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-items")[0]; //<div class="cart-items">
  carItems.innerHTML = "";
  var locStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedProduct"));
  var cartRowContents = locStore.map((item) => addItemToCart(item));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, With your code, it shows the items many times but in different rows. Earlier, it was showing 2 items in a single row. Now, it's showing each item in a different row.

Comment: yes, sorry
I forgot to cleanup the cart, try it now

Comment: Obviously, we can do better by saving the list of of rendered rows or looking them up in DOM. But this solution is the closest to what you have already, so let's try it first

Comment: Now, it works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I know an answer has been accepted but, assuming your item has an ID you can make use of that to make each cart row unique(for updating quantity and deleting cart item).

**PS:** I didn't test this. It's just to optimize and fix your UI issue

```
//add cart item row
function addItemToCart () {
    document.getElementsByClassName("cart-items")[0].insertAdjacentHTML(
        'beforeend',
        `<div class="cart-row" id="cartid-${item.id}">
            <div class="cart-item cart-column">
                <img class="cart-item-image" src="${item.image}" width="100" height="100">
                <span class="cart-item-title">${item.title}</span>
                <span class="cart-item-size">"Rs.${item.sizePrice}"</span>
            </div>
            <span class="cart-price cart-column">${item.price}</span>
            <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
                <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1" id="quantityid-${item.id} onchange="quantityChanged">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="removeCartItem(this)">REMOVE</button>
            </div>
        </div>`      
    )
}

//remove the cart item row
function removeCartItem (input) {
    input.parentNode.remove()
}


/**
 * Render all the items in cart, 
 * call this instead of addItemToCart after an item was added to local storage.
 **/
function renderItemsInCart() {
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-items")[0]; //<div class="cart-items">
  carItems.innerHTML = "";
  var locStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedProduct"));
  var cartRowContents = locStore.map((item) => addItemToCart(item));
}
```

Comment: Yes. I realized this later that I should make use of the ID here. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not access the last element of `locStore` since that would be the latest one right ? Currently you're calling `.map` on the whole **localStorage** items but I am assuming that `addItemToCart` is only called after your `localStorage` is updated with a recent item and you just want the **DOM** to reflect that latest change. I think the below should work :-

```
 var item = locStore[locStore.length-1];
 var cartRowContents = 
        `<div class="cart-item cart-column">
            <img class="cart-item-image" src="${item.image}" width="100" height="100">
            <span class="cart-item-title">${item.title}</span>
            <span class="cart-item-size">"Rs.${item.sizePrice}"</span>
        </div>
        <span class="cart-price cart-column">${item.price}</span>
        <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
            <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
        </div>`;
```

Comment: Your approach seems good. Will try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just empty the whole Cart in the begging of the function, and then let the function populate everything from LocalStorage.